# Spring cloud stream kafka : How to create DLQ configuration for per consumer topic?

Tags: spring, cloud, apache-kafka-streams

Following properties are not working as expected , I want to create a DLQ for each consumer topic after retry

stream:
kafka:
streams :
binder.deserializationExceptionHandler: sendToDlq
bindings:
listener-in-0:
consumer:
enableDql: true
dlqName: topic.dlq
autoCommitOnError: true
autoCommitOffset: true
listener:
ack-mode: manual
binder:
autoCreateTopics: true
brokers: localhost:8080
bindings:
publisher-out-0:
destination: topic.create

I have tried property file as shared but not working as expected